# My Line Color is overlapping. What to do?

Tags: javascript, colors, line

I'm following the JS tutorial in W3schools and make some improve for the code.

Now My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
      <head>
        <style>
           body {
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
           }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
      <script>
      function getAngle(x, y, angle, h) {
    var radians = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    return { x: x + h * Math.cos(radians), y: y + h * Math.sin(radians) };
  }

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var lineWidth = 250;
  var centerx = canvas.width/2;
  var centery = canvas.height/2;
      var axisx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var axisy = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var L1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var L2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var L3 = canvas.getContext('2d');


      axisy.beginPath();
      axisy.moveTo(centerx, 10);
      axisy.lineTo(centerx, 590);
  axisy.strokeStyle = '#000000';
      axisy.stroke();

      axisx.beginPath();
      axisx.moveTo(10, centery);
      axisx.lineTo(590, centery);
  axisx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
      axisx.stroke();


      L1pos = getAngle(centerx, centery, 25, lineWidth);
  L1.moveTo(centerx, centery);
      L1.lineTo(L1pos.x, L1pos.y);
  L1.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  L1.stroke();

  L2pos = getAngle(centerx, centery, 125, lineWidth);
  L2.moveTo(centerx, centery);
      L2.lineTo(L2pos.x, L2pos.y);
  L2.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
  L2.stroke();

  L3pos = getAngle(centerx, centery, 225, lineWidth);
  L3.moveTo(centerx, centery);
      L3.lineTo(L3pos.x, L3pos.y);
  L3.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  L3.stroke();

   </script>
 </body>
```

The result show that all 3 diagonals line (L1, L2, L3) were blue coloured (#0000ff). How to put different color on each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before beginning to draw, you have to call `beginPath`, to flush the previous line. (see [beginPath on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beginpath.asp))

```
 L1.beginPath()
```

see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UX4gC/